# Number column to Var char column without returning decimal value

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

The following expression is returning decimal value

```
TO_VARCHAR(COLUMN_NAME + 10)
```

let say the value of column is 80 , it is ruturning 90.00000
and the COLUMN_NAME in source is number

what to add or change to get the return value as varchar as 90 instead of 90.0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just cast the sum to an integer, first, and then to a varchar.

```
SELECT (COLUMN_NAME + 10)::INT::VARCHAR;
```

You can also use SQL Format Models here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html, but I find them difficult to work with, since you mostly need to know the fixed decimal places of your result, first.  For example,

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR('40' + 10, '99');
```

or

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR('40' + 10, '999');
```

both work, but this doesn't:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR('400' + 10, '99');
```

So, I'd just stick with the first one if I were you, it's just easier.